# Spring JPA + Hibernate(3.5,3.6, 4.0 .....) Integration

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, jpa

HibernateJpaVendorAdapter is used to integrate Spring JPA with Hibernate. For example, the following configuration works:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="trstore" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />

        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```

But as per, Spring's documentation HibernateJpaVendorAdapter has only been tested with Hibernate 3.3.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.html

Does Spring plan to support this(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter ) for more recent Hibernate releases like 3.5, 3.6 4.0 etc ?

If not, are there any alternative recommendations on how to integrate Spring JPA with Hibernate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can raise an issue about that in spring JIRA. I suspect the documentation hasn't been updated. The adapter is very, very simple (check the [source code](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java)), and there is nothing that can go wrong. We are using it with hibernate 3.5 in production without any issues.